# How to upload files to Dropbox ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload files to Dropbox. Upload is not working. The upload method is given below.

```
//  RootViewController.m

-(NSString *)getDocumentPath{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:FILENAME];
    return path;
}
-(IBAction)download:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"download pressed");
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.restClient loadFile:@"/dbTutorial.plist" intoPath:[self getDocumentPath]];

}
-(IBAction)upload:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"upload pressed");
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
    NSString *path = [self getDocumentPath];
    [self.itemArray writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    [self.itemArray uploadFile:FILENAME toPath:@"/" fromPath:path];// When I build this is the warning that I get:NSMutableArray may not respond to -uploadFiletoPath:fromPath


}
```

Thank you very much. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

`[self.restClient uploadFile:FILENAME toPath:@"/" fromPath:path];`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i track the progress of the upload?

I checked the
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress 
        forFile:(NSString*)destPath from:(NSString*)srcPath;


But could not make out how to use this...

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)uploadPhoto
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Kallol.jpg"];

    NSString *pathString = @"/Photos";

    [self.restClient uploadFile:@"Kallol12.jpg" toPath:pathString fromPath:path];

}
```

I tried with above code and work nicely.........